# Contour integration and Limits

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, contour-integration

> For $r$ a positive real number let $f(r):=\int_{C_{r}} \frac{\sin(z)}{z}dz$, where $C_r$ is the contour $re^{i\theta}$, $0 \leq \theta \leq \pi$. What is $\lim_{r\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(r)}{r}$ ?

I am unable to integrate on the contour since the singularity $0$ lies on the contour.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The singularity is not on the contour except for $r=0$ (which isn't particularly relevant since you're taking the limit) -- your contour is a circle of radius $r$. Perhaps consider one of the usual techniques for evaluating the integral, e.g. residue theorem or whatever you're most familiar with?

Comment: But, we're given $0 \leq \theta \leq \pi$. So, I believe it represents a semi-circle with diameter implies singularity 0 lies on the contour.

Comment: My bad, for some reason I thought it was the whole circle. Even so, there isn't an issue with $0$ lying on the contour for the same reason mentioned: $0$ is not on the contour unless the radius is $0$. Every point on $C_r$ is a fixed distance $r$ from the origin, owing to the parameterization of $re^{i \theta}$, so $0$ can only be on $C_r$ when $r=0$. Which isn't a concern because we're taking the limit as $r \to 0$ ($r$ need not be $0$ at any point).

Comment: I don't know how to proceed for the semi-circle as given above. Could you please propose a hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac {f(r)} r=i\int_0^{\pi} \frac {sin (re^{it})} r dt$ and $\frac {\sin z }z \to 1$ as $ r \to 0$. Hence the answer is $i\int_0^{\pi}e^{it} dt=-2$.

[ It is easy to justify the interchange of limit and integral in this case].

Comment: Sir, I don't understand why it is easy to justify the 'interchange'. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @HeavyMetaL If $f_n \to f$ uniformly then $\int_a^{b}f_n(x)dx \to \int_a^{b} f(x)dx$. Can you check uniform convergence in this case?

Comment: Okk, sure sir. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Since,$$(\forall z\in\mathbb C):\frac{\sin z}z=1-\frac{z^2}{3!}+\frac{z^4}{5!}-\cdots,$$the function $\frac{\sin z}z$ has a primitive:$$F(z)=z-\frac{z^3}{3\times3!}+\frac{z^5}{5\times5!}-\cdots$$and therefore\begin{align}\lim_{r\to0}\frac1r\int_{C_r}\frac{\sin z}z\,\mathrm dz&=\lim_{r\to0}\frac{F(re^{\pi i})}r-\frac{F(re^{0\times i})}r\\&=\lim_{r\to0}e^{\pi i}\frac{F(re^{\pi i})}{re^{\pi i}}-\frac{F(re^{0\times i})}r\\&=e^{\pi i}-1\text{ (because $F'(0)=1$)}\\&=-2.\end{align}